# There are fewer rows in the dataframe after one hot encoding

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-processing

I have a dataset which I'd like to one hot encode using **sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder**. My problem is that after the encoding, the result contains fewer rows than the original dataset (the difference is 5).
Here is my code:

```
one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False)
X_cat = pd.DataFrame(
            one_hot_encoder.fit_transform(X[categorical_vars]),
            columns=one_hot_encoder.get_feature_names(categorical_vars)
)
```

Thanks for any advice in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you get less output columns because you have some unknown categorical features. Because you set the keyword 'handle_unknown' to ignore, thesecolumns are skipped.

If you give me some of your sample data, I can test it for you and give you a better explanation. Otherwise, I can advise you to read this [post](https://medium.com/hugo-ferreiras-blog/dealing-with-categorical-features-in-machine-learning-1bb70f07262d). It explains well the purpose of the 'handle_unknown' keyword and why and when to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My issue is according to the rows, not the columns. However, I don't think that the problem is with the "handle_unknown" keyword. The above-mentioned data is the data on which the encoder was fitted. The ignorance of the unknown values comes into view when I transform a set without fitting (e.g. my test set).

Comment: I read the post provided in your answer, where I found that the "category_encoders" package's OneHotEncoder can deal with my problem. Thank you for your answer again. :)

Comment: No problem. Thank you for closing :)